# CoreData fetch does not always return value

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

What I want to do is store data using core data.
I've got code like below with fetching, my problem is that sometimes when I run application wpis2.count gives 0 no idea why (i've got information: "data not loaded" without any error). Is there any way that I should prepare core data before use? 
Ustawienia are:

```
extension Ustawienia {

    @NSManaged var ust: String?
    @NSManaged var wym: String?

}
```

PS. Data exists for sure, because when I run application again it works OK.  Any idea how solve it?

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)



        let entity2 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Ustawienia")
        entity2.fetchLimit = 1
        do{
            let wpis2 = try moc3.executeFetchRequest(entity2) as! [NSManagedObject]
            let ust = wpis2 as [NSManagedObject]
            if (wpis2.count==1){
                let ustawienia = wpis2[0] as! Ustawienia
                if (ustawienia.ust=="n"){
                    tabela="n"
                }
                else
                {
                    tabela="p"
                }
                if (ustawienia.wym=="w"){
                    wymienniki="w"
                }
                else
                {
                    wymienniki="p"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog("data not loaded")

            }

        }
        catch
        {
            fatalError("error \(error)")
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've inserted the data **and** saved it?

Comment: It looks like you'll get the `data not loaded` message any time `wpis2.count` is not equal to 1. Have you verified that it's not 2, or 3, or...?

Comment: Thanks for replay. Well it's strange cause I test it in one run: enter by menu to see view (in that view at begin I load core data by code above) I see it's OK, then I go back to previous view, I want again see view and I got "data not load". Tom thanks for tip that it might be more then one: but it isn't that.. I checked and when I get error wpis2.count = 0.